# How to Animate a Border Below a Horizontal Nav Item from Left to Right

Tags: jquery, css

Id like to animate a border in a horizontal navigation from left to right on hover.  The closest example I have been able to find is the one here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine/ but its not what im looking for.

I just want to hover and have an underline simply draw from left to right.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I guess you will have to fake this, since you cannot animate a border from left to right. You can add another element though, give it a background color and then animate its width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="menuitem">
    Menu Item
    <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menuitem {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #FFE;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menuitem span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    height: 3px;
    background: #000;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}
.menuitem:hover span {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/QUMgy/**

Comment: Pure CSS, Excellent!  Thanks so much. Here is the same technique applied to an unordered list for anyone that needs it: http://jsfiddle.net/wRJ3P/.

Answer (score 1):

Other workaround could be :

```
1) Make another element say a div and place it below the Nav bar.
2) Animate the that div when user hovers over any of the menu items.
3) And animate back when the pointer moves out of the navigation bar's parent.
```

This is the simplest thing that i could think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **CSS**

```
.menuitem {
    display: inline-block;
}
.menuitem:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
 }
 .menuitem:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
 }
```

[**Live Demo**](http://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/JEgbPy)

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: grey;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href ="#">Test Link</a>
```

Comment: You will need to add the underline as a pseudo element :after and work on it to get the animated underline as shown on the code.